# Query to fetch multiple data by joining multiple tables using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need one help .I need to fetch some data after joining the multiple table using PHP and Mysql so i need the appropriate query for that.I am explaining my table structure below.

> db_order:

```
id     order_id    promocode

1      10           A12016

2       11          A12016
```

> db_order_product:

```
id   order_id   pro_data_id  quantity

1     10         20          2

2     10         22          3

3     11         20          1
```

> db_product_info:

```
pro_data_id   product_name

20            abc

22            xyz
```

I have tried something like below but its not working.

```
$sqlqry="select * from db_order order by id desc";
$orderqry=mysqli_query($con,$sqlqry);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($orderqry)){
    $order_id=$row['order_id'];
    $sqlproqry="select * from db_order_products where order_id='".$order_id."'";
    $proqry=mysqli_query($con,$sqlproqry);
    while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($proqry)){
        $product_data_id=$row1['pro_data_id'];
        $sqldataqry="select * from db_product_data where pro_data_id='".$product_data_id."'";
        $prodataqry=mysqli_query($con,$sqldataqry);
        while($prodatarow=mysqli_fetch_assoc($prodataqry)){
            $pro_id=$prodatarow['pro_Id'];
            $sqlpro="select * from db_product_info where pro_Id='".$pro_id."'";
            $prodata=mysqli_query($con,$sqlpro);
            $prorow=mysqli_fetch_array($prodata);
        }
    }
$result[]=array('id'=>$row['id'],'order_id'=>$row['order_id'],'promocode'=>$row['promocode'],'order_pro_id'=>$row1['id'],'pro_data_id'=>$row1['pro_data_id'],'pro_quantity'=>$row1['quantity'],'product_name'=>$prorow['Product_name']);
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Here i need first user will go to `db_order` table fetch all value and according to the `order_id` the all data should fetch from `db_order_product` then as per `pro_data_id` from `db_order_product` table it will fetch data from `db_product_info` table and finaly return all data in an array.Please help me.

Comment: Where is your query? You're not expecting us to write it for you, are you? This sounds like a simple `JOIN` between the 3 tables, very basic SQL. Please show what you've tried, and explain the problem you're having with it so we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a simple `JOIN`

```
SELECT o.id, o.order_id, o.promocode, p.id AS order_pro_id, p.prod_data_id, p.quantity AS pro_quantity, i.product_name
FROM db_order AS o
JOIN db_order_products AS p ON o.order_id = p.order_id
JOIN db_product_data AS d ON p.pro_data_id = d.pro_data_id
JOIN db_product_info AS i ON i.pro_Id = d.pro_Id
ORDER BY o.id DESC
```

Comment: As you can see there is two order_id as `10` in `db_order_product:` table.Will it work accordingly.

Comment: Yes. `JOIN` produces a cross-product of all matching rows.

Comment: @ Barmar : as you can see the first two table `db_order: and  db_order_product:` has auto increment column name(`id`)  are same and i need both id.Can you tell how can i fetch both using different key.

Comment: Now all the columns will be fetched with the names you use in your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

you must fix you query:

use this query instead:

```
  select * from db_order,db_order_product,db_product_info where db_order.order_id=db_order_product.order_id and db_order_product.pro_data_id=db_product_info.pro_data_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT dor.id,dordor.order_id,dor.promocode
FROM db_order AS dor
JOIN db_order_product AS dop ON dop.order_id = dor.order_id
JOIN db_product_info as dpi ON dpi.pro_data_id=dop.pro_data_id
```